# how to hide id from url in Laravel 6?

Tags: laravel, routes

hide id from url

```
https://wallpaperaccess.in/photo/162/download-wallpaper
```

i want url like this

```
https://wallpaperaccess.in/photo/download-wallpaper
```

**ImagesController.php**

```
public function show($id, $slug = null ) {

        $response = Images::findOrFail($id);

        $uri = $this->request->path();

        if( str_slug( $response->title ) == '' ) {

                $slugUrl  = '';
            } else {
                $slugUrl  = '/'.str_slug( $response->title );
            }

            $url_image = 'photo/'.$response->id.$slugUrl;

            //<<<-- * Redirect the user real page * -->>>
            $uriImage     =  $this->request->path();
            $uriCanonical = $url_image;

            if( $uriImage != $uriCanonical ) {
                return redirect($uriCanonical);
            }
```

**Route**

```
// Photo Details
Route::get('photo/{id}/{slug?}','ImagesController@show');
```

**NOTE:** i don't have any slug column in database, so can we use title as slug?

Comment: If you want to hide the id from the url, the you should edit your route to be `Route::get('photo/{slug?}','ImagesController@show');` and then you'd also have to edit your method to `public function show($slug = null )`. Not really sure if that's what you're looking for or not though since it looks like you're using id to look up the image?

Comment: This is possible `Route::get('photo/{slug?}','ImagesController@show');` store the `id` value on session and get it on controller from session `Images::findOrFail(session()->get('id'));`

Comment: Can you use uuid and replace the bigint id?

Comment: its simple you just encrypt and dycript your id in url

Comment: i edit my route to `Route::get('photo/{slug?}','ImagesController@show');`  and also edit method to `public function show($slug = null )` but it still show id instant of slug

Answer (score 0):

You should add a column field `slug` and auto-generate it from `title`

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

$slug = Str::slug($request->input('title'), '-');
```

In `Models\Image.php`

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug';
}
```

In `routes\web.php`

```
Route::get('photo/{image:slug}','ImagesController@show');
```

In `app\Http\Controllers\ImagesController.php`

```
use app\Models\Image.php;

...
public function show(Image $image)
{
    // controller will automatically find $image with slug in url
    // $image_id = $image->id;
    return view('your.view', ['image' => $image]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use a slug in the URL instead of an id, you'll need to...

1. Create a column in your table where you store the slug. A good way to make a slug unique is to append the actual id at the end. If you really don't want to see the id anywhere, you have no choice, you'll have to ensure the slug is unique yourself (there are a lot of ways to achieve this).

This is one way to automatically create an unique slug:

Make sure the `slug` column is nullable, then open your model and add these methods.

They are called "model events".

- `created` is called when the model is, well, created.
- `updating` is called when you are updating the model but before it's actually updated.

Using `created` and `updating` should automatically create the slug when you create or update a `Images` instance.

```php
    protected static function booted()
    {
        parent::booted();

        static::created(function (Images $images) {
            $images->slug = Str::slug($images->title.'-'.$images->id);
            $images->save();
        });

        static::updating(function (Images $images) {
            $images->slug = Str::slug($images->title.'-'.$images->id);
        });
    }
```

*From a SEO point of view, updating the slug when the title change is arguably not a good practice, so you might want to omit this part (`static::updating...`), it's up to you.*

2. Go to your model and add the following method:

```php
/**
 * Get the route key for the model.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug'; //or whatever you call the slug column
}
```

This way, the router will resolve your model by the slug, not the id.

3. In your route file, remove the id and change the name of the slug to match the name of your model:

```php
Route::get('photo/{images}','ImagesController@show'); //here I'm assuming your model is Images from what I see in your controller
```

4. In your controller, change the declaration of your `show` method to this:

```php
public function show(Images $images)
{
   dd($images);

// if you did all this correctly, $images should be the Images corresponding to the slug in the url.
// if you did something wrong, $images will be an empty Images instance
//
//
// your code...
}
```

---

*`Images` should be renamed to `Image`, models should not be plural. However, it should not make any difference here.*

Comment: I created slug column. I need to add slug to the table one by one myself

Comment: What you can do is to use the `created` event. I'll edit my answer with an example.

Comment: please example  me

Comment: I updated my answer you can find an example of how to automatically create and update a slug. Note that, for the uniqueness, I used the id. It's not a problem for SEO purpose, it's unique, not changing over time and technically OK too. If you really want to use something else, you'll have to implement this logic yourself (for instance, use the `title` and append a `uniqid()` at the end, something like that.

Comment: Quick note: it's important that the slug column is nullable in your database, because with the example I added, your `Images` will first be added without slug and you'll have an error if that's not possible (not nullable).

Comment: i did same way as you said but it's not working... but when i use `Route::get('/photo/{images}', function(Images $image){
  return $image->title;
});` its show 404 error...

Comment: Triple check that the slug in your url is exactly the same as the slug in the database (you can also edit your question with all these details)